# IIF in With Member comparing dates

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am very new to `MDX` and have a basic question. I would like a calculated measure which returns one value for dates less than a specified date, and another value if greater than a specified date. I have attempted:

```
with member [measures].[tempmeasure] as 
    IIF
       (
        [Date].[Date].CurrentMember < [Date].[Date].&[20100501]
        , 1
        , 2
       )

select 
   [Date].[Date].Members
   * 
   [measures].[tempmeasure] on columns
from [MyCube]
```

And this does not seem to work. That is using `MS SSAS 2008`. 
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below expression

```
IIF
   (
    [Date].[Date].Currentmember.MemberValue  < 
    [Date].[Date].&[20100501].MemberValue
    , 1
    , 2
   )
```

I have tested it is working as expected.....

Please let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
IIF([Date].[Date].CurrentMember < [Date].[Date].&[20100501], 1, 2)
```

you're comparing two tuple values and not the date members themselves.
You can have a look [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/members.html) for a tutorial on tuples, sets, etc...

As you're using AS, I think you can use the DataDiff function to compute the number of days between your two dates:

```
DateDiff("d", [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue, [Date].[Date].&[20100501].MemberValue )
```

Otherwise, you may have some member properties available for that purpose:

```
IIF([Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Properties( 'prop-name', TYPED ) < [Date].[Date].&[20100501].Properties( 'prop-name', TYPED ) , 1, 2)
```

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not trying to compute a difference between dates, I want my calculated measure to have one value when the date is before a given date, and another value when the date is greater than that date.

Comment: Am I missing something ? IIF( DateDiff( ... ) > 0, 1 , 2 ) or < 0 should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

IIF expects a logical expression which returns a boolean value. I think in your case 
`[Date].[Date].CurrentMember` will return a dimension value, a set. Less than operator in this case will cause a syntax error.